# Алгоритм преобразования одномерного массива в многомерный с помощью значения глубины

Tags: php, массивы

Добрый день! Есть массив:

```
[
    [
        'depth' => 0,
        'children' => []
    ],
    [
        'depth' => 1,
        'children' => []
    ],
    [
        'depth' => 2,
        'children' => []
    ],
    [
        'depth' => 3,
        'children' => []
    ],
    [
        'depth' => 1,
        'children' => []
    ],
    [
        'depth' => 0,
        'children' => []
    ],
    ...
]
```

где 'depth' => значение глубины для текущего элемента. Значение depth заранее никак не ограниченно, но всегда идет по порядку сверху вниз. Так вот, как из вышеуказанного массива сделать такой:

```
[
    [
        'depth' => 0,
        'children' => [
            [
                'depth' => 1,
                'children' => [
                    [
                        'depth' => 2,
                        'children' => [
                            [
                                'depth' => 3,
                                'children' => []
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                'depth' => 1,
                'children' => []
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'depth' => 0,
        'children' => []
    ],
    ...
]
```

Comment: Можно так - храните стэк с текущими узлами, проходите сверху вниз исходный массив, если depth в массиве больше чем depth в вершине стэка, тогда добавляем ребёнком в узел вершины стэка этот узел, также добавляем этот узел в стэк, если меньше или равен depth вершины стэка, тогда выпихиваем их стэка до тех пор пока не будет больше чем у вершины стэка и тогда только добавляем к ребёнку вершины стэка этот элемент и добавляем элемент в стэк. Повторяем.

Comment: Также можно решить с помощью рекурсивного вызова функции, но по сути рекурсивный вызов это и есть тоже использование неявное стэка. В функцию передаём глубину которую функция должна обработать и позицию в исходном массиве, задача функции для заданной глубины собрать всех детей. В итоге если функция встречает элемент который равен её глубине то добавляет ребёнка, если меньше то возвращает из функции результат (заполненных детей) если больше тогда рекурсивно вызывает заполнение детей последнего своего ребёнка.

Answer (score 0):

Практически удалось решить

```
<?php

$arr = [
    [
        'depth' => 0,
        'children' => []
    ],
    [
        'depth' => 1,
        'children' => []
    ],
    [
        'depth' => 2,
        'children' => []
    ],
    [
        'depth' => 3,
        'children' => []
    ],
    [
        'depth' => 4,
        'children' => []
    ],
    [
        'depth' => 5,
        'children' => []
    ],
    [
        'depth' => 1,
        'children' => []
    ],
    [
        'depth' => 1,
        'children' => []
    ],
    [
        'depth' => 0,
        'children' => []
    ]
];

function hardArray($arr, $height){
    $back = [];
    $memory = [];
    $return = [];
    foreach($arr as $value){
        if( $height == $value['depth']) {
             if ( !sizeof($back) ) $back = $value;
             else {
                $return[] = [ 'depth'=> $height, 'children' => hardArray( $memory, $height+1)  ];
                $memory = [];
                $back = $value;
             }
        }
        else $memory[] = $value;
    }
    $return[] = ( sizeof($memory) > 1 )? [ 'depth'=> $height, 'children' => hardArray( $memory, $height+1)  ] : $back ;
    return $return;
}
print_r( hardArray( $arr, 0) );
```

Comment: надо будет только выяснить почему он не воспринимает последний элемент 'depth' => 5